# Understanding how software testing works and what to test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

**Intro:** 
I've seen lots of topics here on SO about software testing and other terms I don't understand.

**Problem:** 
As a beginner developer I, unfortunately, have no idea how software testing works, not even how to test a simple function. This is a shame, but thats the truth. I also hope this question can help others beginners developers too.

**Question:** 
Can you help me to understand this subject a little bit more?

Maybe some questions to start would help:

- When I develop a function, how should I test it? For example: when working with a sum function, should I test every input value possible or just some limits? How about testing functions with strings as parameters?
- In a big program, do I have to test every single piece of code of it? When you guys program do you test every code written?
- How automated test works and how can I try one? How tools for automated testing works and what they do?
- I`ve heard about unit testing. Can I have a brief explanation on this?
- What is a testing framework?

If possible please post some code with examples to clarify the ideas.

Any help on this topic is very welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start with the obvious:

**How does testing work ?** In test-driven development you first think about the functionality you want to implement and then write a test for it. In the example you gave of a sum function it is quite obvious what it should do. You then write a test that makes sure that the summation worked.

Unit tests should be as lightweight as possible so you can run them each time you hit the build button. When you do this now in this example your test will fail, because you have not yet implemented a sum function.

Now you write the actual function and continue debugging and implementing until the test passes. Then you are sure you have implemented the feature you wanted.

**Now how should you design your test ?** You cannot test all, that is impossible. As an example lets say you take user input you have to validate. Then it would be a natural thing to write at least two test cases for that validation code: one that makes sure that valid input is parsed as such. The second test case gets invalid input and you make sure that it fails, raises an exception or whatever behavior you desired. So in this case it is good to have a positive test which is expected to pass and a negative test which checks if invalid input is not validated.

**When should one test?** As I mentioned before the test should be lightweight enough so that they can be run on each build. And yes, run all of them. This makes sure that you do not miss a dependency in your code that breaks things far away from the point you edited.

**Can anything be tested ?** Well, usually methods that rely on external ressources are hard to test. What I mean by that are databases, network connections or specific hardware and drivers. It can be done but then you have to set up a larger test setup.

**Bugfixing and tests** A typical scenario where test get really useful is if you are squeezing bugs. Not literally of course. If you have a bug you have to fix, first try to write a test for it. And then fix your code until your test passes. From this point on this test "watches over your code" that this bug will never come back again.

**What do you gain by testing ?** In my opinion there are many things

1. More modular, easier to maintain code because it has to be testable
2. Confidence. Having a code base that is largely tested gives you the confidence that it works as expected and stays like this.
3. You find bugs early. This means you can fix them more easily.

It takes some effort to get used to using tests but I think it is worth it. Especially if you are writing libraries of some kind.

Comment: Something is not clear yet. You said that everytime I build my code, unit test must pass? This mean that I must write a function to test my sum function, and this test function must call my sum function everytime my app runs?

Comment: Well yes and no :) You usually have two build configurations of some kind: 1. let's call it debug config. This one is build with full debugger symbols and is used during coding. In this configuration you really want your unit test to run each time you build.
The second configuration would be a release config. In this you do not do any unit testing and also leave away the debugging symbols and enable all optimizations in the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Can you post some examples here please? (code and unit test).

Comment: @RHaguiuda Well that strongly depends which language you are using. For many if not all language there are test frameworks available. Checking out the Wikipedia is a good starting point to get an overview.

Answer (score 3):

Well, 
Usually, there're three kinds of tests. Unit Tests, System tests and QA tests. Unit tests, as the name suggests, test small units - separate functions and classes.

For all modern development environments there're unit test frameworks. There's Nunit for .net, as well as MS unit test framework in Visual Studio, CPPUnit for C++, JUnit, etc. All meant for one thing: connect to parts of your program, run your pre-defined scripts and report error.

CPPUnit, for example, is based on macros like CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL, meant to be used as something like this: CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(sum(arr), 17). And it would say if it's not equal, in which case the test will be considered failed.

You are supposed to develop the tests for every function, and after that - you are not afraid to change and optimize the code. It is generally referred to a "repeatability" - ability to do a complex action, such as full testing of all codebase, with a single click.

Unit tests are required for every moden software development, because the experience shows that they improve development speed. It is also suggested that unit test code may serve as a kind of "documentation" for the library.

System tests are automated tests of larger, high-level functionality. The idea of system tests is to feed clean input (such as databases, user input, etc) to test the whole thing, validating the output against pre-defined resutls. It is essential that the system ouput is deterministic, and depends only on the input. Every time the system changes, the system tests change also.

TDD is a cool-sounding bad idea, suggesting that you should not develop anything before implementing the proper automated tests, and then writing code to satisfy the tests. It is regardedd as failure, because changes in the design are inevitable during development, and a small design change usually causes drastic changes in the unit tests.

Manual QA is the final, and most important type of software testing. The idea is to prepare a test plan, whcih is done during design and coding phases, collecting all ideas developers had during coding of every if statement, how to actually make this particular if statement run along the less expected code path. The QA personnel, meant to be capable of anything that can be done with the program without development environment, can follow the resulting test procedure and their own ideas, to find more bugs.

Comment: +1 for the nice overview. However, I strongly disagree with the blanket statement "TDD... is regardedas failure". TDD may not be for everyone and for every project, but TDD works well even with a changing design (tests are refactored together with production code).

Comment: thanks, well, maybe. I though have never seen in my whole career that strict TDD lead to good results...

Comment: Pavel, Thanks for your repply. I did not understand one thing: When you say that I must develop tests for every function, this means that everyfunction I code, I must also code a another function that tests the code? If this true, all my code will be filled with test functions?

Comment: -1 for stating that TDD is a bad idea, without adding even "IMHO". Modern refactoring tools make your concern meaningless. A "small design change causing drastic changes in the unit tests" is usually a sign of poorly written unit tests. In fact, used properly, TDD even _helps_ getting a better design quicker.

Comment: @Peter there's lots of information on why TDD is antipattern, nothing IMHO in this.

Comment: Maybe you could have provided a reference in your answer then... which you are still free to do btw. Anyway, even if lots of people think TDD is bad, another lot of people think it is good, so it is not generally "regarded as failure". I have no problem with controversial opinions - _if_ they are backed by evidence/references and _if_ it is clearly mentioned that the coin has (at least) two sides. Your answer does neither.

Comment: That's really a GYIF - but ok. Also, I have NEVER in my life seen anybody doing a real TDD, enforced by management, resulting in anything good.

Answer (score 1):

I found the book 'JUnit Pocket Guide' by Kent Beck as an excellent (and cheap and compact!) introduction to Unit Testing: the book is split roughly into sections on the merits of test-driven programming and general testing techniques and then goes into the specifics of the JUnit framework (which he co-created).

http://www.amazon.co.uk/JUnit-Pocket-Guide-Kent-Beck/dp/0596007434/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1276811600&sr=8-7

With regard to your request for some illustrative examples of Unit Testing; this JUnit Primer isn't bad:

http://www.clarkware.com/articles/JUnitPrimer.html#testcase

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the tests into three big branches (actually there are more, but if you are a beginner you have to understand the base first): Alpha, Beta, Full working code.

1. In alpha you try every single value for every single piece of code.
2. In beta you give the presumably working application to the world, in order to get a feedback from testers and improve it.
3. When your app is fully working you just have to wait for the error-report (it always comes) of a user who discovered that issue and fix it with a patch.

> When I develop a function, how should I test it? For example: when working with a sum function, should I test every input value possible or just some limits? How about testing functions with strings as parameters?

In alpha you have to think about ALL the possibilities your code can be dial with.
In the case of a sum() function, they are a few, but if you are developing let's say a big database server application, you need to take in account every possible input and handle every possible error, think of the end user as a stupid person or even as a malicious cracker.

> In a big program, do I have to test every single piece of code of it? When you guys program do you test every code written?

I do, you should, microsoft doesn't. (catch the joke ;) )

> How automated test works and how can I try one? How tools for automated testing works and what they do?

No automation can overcome human intelligence and a good debugger (that's the only tool you really need!)

> I`ve heard about unit testing. Can I have a brief explanation on this?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing

> What is a testing framework?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_automation_framework

Answer (score 1):

**What to test**

There are a couple of really useful concepts that helped me work this out:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_partitioning
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary-value_analysis

Equivalence partitioning says "Running the test in this context with these events is equivalent to this other test over here, so I don't need to do both."

Boundary analysis says "Here's the point at which a change in context or a different event causes a different outcome, so I will want tests on either side of this boundary."

Thinking about these can really help to minimize the number of tests you need to write.

**When to test**

I always manually test my code to make sure that it works. I often write an additional unit test which covers every line of code I'm about to write. The unit test fails before I write the code to make it pass. If it's something a user will do, then I often write an acceptance test or automated scenario, too.

**Automated testing**

Automated testing means either scripting or recording a test so that you don't have to do it manually - your script or code will do it for you. There are two kinds of automation tools: BDD- or English-readable acceptance-testing fixtures which let you write the scripts, and automation wrappers which let you automate more easily. So for instance, you might choose to use GivWenZen or Fitnesse as your fixture, and Selenium as your web automation tool.

If you've got Visual Studio 2008+ you could download the source code from here and try out the scenario to see it run:

http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/

**Unit testing**

In its strictest sense, Unit Testing means testing an element of code in isolation from all other elements of code. We use mocks in place of real pieces of code that our Code Under Test requires. In reality we are often pragmatic about the nature of "units" - I don't mock out domain objects, for instance.

However, unit testing in the way that most people use it isn't really about testing. Mostly it's a mechanism for achieving clean design and separation of responsibilities, because you're forced into this by trying to test it.

I like to think of unit testing as "writing an example of how I'm going to use the code I'm about to write". The example happens to reside in a unit-testing framework and be executable.

**Testing frameworks**

- Unit-testing frameworks help you to run a lot of tests together.
- Acceptance-testing frameworks help you to run a larger scenario and are often English-readable.
- Automation frameworks usually sit underneath your English-readable frameworks and help you to interact with an application.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

When I develop a function, how should I test it? For example: when working with a sum function, should I test every input value possible or just some limits? How about testing functions with strings as parameters?  You can use boundary value analysis black box testing type

In a big program, do I have to test every single piece of code of it? When you guys program do you test every code written?  Yes, You have to confirm each module working as per expected results

How automated test works and how can I try one? How tools for automated testing works and what they do? Automation Testing depends on different factors ex. Project scope , Time, cost , available resource etc . Recommend you explore automation testing concepts

I`ve heard about unit testing. Can I have a brief explanation on this?
What is a testing framework? . Depends on your programming language selection because in python unittest provided and java have another unit test framework

Overall need to go through Automation testing concepts and application.

Answer (score 0):

**When I develop a function, how should I test it? For example: when working with a sum function, should I test every input value possible or just some limits? How about testing functions with strings as parameters?**

First it starts with defining the functionality of the application which is used to create the test case. Either you are testing manually or through automation, you need to define output that you want to achieve on every input to identify the limits of test case.

**In a big program, do I have to test every single piece of code of it? When you guys program do you test every code written?**

Testing can be consuming at times since it is a process that needs to be followed in parts. The code is put to test in parts for every defined functionality. However, if you are working on an application that has a scope for code reusability from the past codes that performs fine, then that part could either be skipped or worked through automation rather than manually checking the code and the output.

**How automated test works and how can I try one? How tools for automated testing works and what they do?**

Automated tests are usually done through automation test tools that are made to run test codes for checking a software or application. For example, selenium is an open-source test automation tool that can automate tests using web browsers. It provides you interface to write test scripts in various programming languages (Ruby, Java, NodeJS, PHP, Perl, Python, and C#) for different browsers and operating systems.

**I`ve heard about unit testing. Can I have a brief explanation on this?**

Unit testing is a testing practice in which individual functions of the software are tested. The primary purpose of unit testing is to check every unit or smallest function of application, usually which involves one or a few inputs that leads to common output.

**What is a testing framework?**

Testing framework is a combination of tools and procedures that are followed for testing an application, software or website. In short, it is a set of rules for designing test cases.